# Twitter Digits 1.15.1 install error (Could not build module 'DigitsKit' || Use of undeclared identifier 'Digits')

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

While installing Digits 1.15.1 in iOS app following errors occurs in AppDelegate.m file:

1. Could not build module 'DigitsKit' at import statement `#import <DigitsKit/DigitsKit.h>`
2. Use of undeclared identifier 'Digits' at `[Fabric with:@[[Digits class]]]` statement in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

Comment: Thank you @Melissa Avery-Weir for the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to **Project Name -> Build Settings -> Apple LLVM 7.0-Language-Modules**

Set **Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)** to No (Default - Yes).

This will solve both errors. But it will show another errors in Digits.h file

**Solve errors**

Navigate to `Digits.h` file and remove `__TVOS_UNAVAILABLE` from all error statements

Now Build and Run the project that will generate another error statements.

**Solve errors**

Navigate to **Project Name -> Build Settings -> Apple LLVM 7.0-Language-Modules**

Set **Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)** to Yes (Default - No).

Build and Run the project and have fun.